# Debug AS3 in Flash CS4, how to watch a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

I am debugging AS3 in Flash CS4, a variable becomes NULL but I don't know who changes it at when. Is it possible to watch this variable and when the value changes to null, it stops?

Thanks.
Bin

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, because I've never thrown an error (on purpose) in AS3. Can you change the property to as setter and then insert:

```
public var function set myVar(v:*):void{
    if(v == null){
        throw new Error("Its null!")
    }
    _myVar = myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from top menu: window > debug panels > variables. 
That should make a huge list of variables visible.